# Recurring events Yearly in full calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am displaying the Date of Birth of the persons in the Full calendar ex:17-July-1992. I want to have this events entry in all years like 17-July-2014, 17-July-2015, 17-July-2016,etc. Automatically.

```
events: [{
                    title: 'user1',
                    start: '2015-04-09',
                    description: 'birthday_event',
                    backgroundColor: Metronic.getBrandColor('blue')
                    },{
                    title: 'user2',
                    start: '2015-04-08',
                    description: 'birthday_event',
                    backgroundColor: Metronic.getBrandColor('blue')
                    },{
                    title: 'user3',
                    start: '2015-04-14',
                    description: 'birthday_event',
                    backgroundColor: Metronic.getBrandColor('blue')
                    }
]
```

this events are displaying correctly in the full calendar i want to create the events dynamically

Comment: show some code please..

Comment: @Raja Could you please give an example on how you handled this problem? I have been wanting to do the repetition monthly and yearly aswell. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use viewRender event and assign current year to the date.

Answer (score 0):

This is an additional functionality that has been awaited for an long time. [Follow the link here to track the progress](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=116).

I highly recommend that it should be done at server side, a little manipulation of the database will be required. You can built your own logic or just follow the links mentioned to get an clearer view.

Here is an good article that will help you to get a grip on how to solve the problem. [Click here](http://fajitanachos.com/Fullcalendar-and-recurring-events/)

I strongly recommend you to read this [Link Here](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/recurring.pdf) For table structure and complete flow.